# Study the convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^\alpha\cdot\ln\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right),\ \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\text{Study the convergence of }\sum_{n\geq 1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^\alpha\cdot\ln\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right),\ \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$$

I'm quite stuck on this one, so any help would be appreciated! What I managed to prove so far is that for $\alpha> 2$, the sum is convergent as such: $a_n=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})^\alpha}\cdot\ln\frac{n+2}{n+1}$
$$\begin{cases} \ln\frac{n+2}{n+1}\text{ is strictly decreasing and its limit is }0 \text{ and}\\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})^\alpha} \text{ converges for }\alpha> 2\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow \text{From Abel's criterion/test, the sum converges}$$

For $\alpha<-2$, I'm not sure if I did it correctly, but what I tried is:
$$L = \lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^\alpha\cdot\ln\frac{n+2}{n+1} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^{\beta}}\ln\frac{n+2}{n+1}, \text{ where } \beta = -\alpha \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow L=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})^\beta\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{\frac{1}{n+1}}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})^\beta}{n+1} \neq0, \text{ for }\beta\geq2\Rightarrow\alpha\leq -2$$
Thus, for $\alpha<-2$, the sum does not converge. However, I'm not exactly sure if I'm allowed to substitute $\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ with $1$.

For any other $\alpha$, that is $\alpha\in(-2,2]$, I'm not sure how to prove convergence/divegence (besides for $0$ which is easy). Once again, I would really appreciate help with this problem!

Comment: From what you have written, you seem to have understood that the term $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ behaves asymptotically like $1/\sqrt{n}$ (or rather half of this), and the term $\ln((n+2)/(n+1))$ behaves asymptotically like $1/n$. So in total our summand is asymptotically equivalent to $n^{-1-\alpha/2}$. Can you see when this converges?

Comment: In general, try to avoid using Abel's test for series of non negative terms. Don't think I've ever seen such a series where this test was the simplest solution. For series of positive terms we have lots of great convergence tests. Here you can solve it all using the limit comparison test.

Comment: @RedundantAunt This is interesting, didn't know I could think of the problem this way. Thank you for your time and answer, it was quite enlightening!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the asymptotic expansion you have:
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\sqrt{n\left(1+\frac1n\right)} -\sqrt n\sim\sqrt n\left(1+\frac1{2n}-1\right)=\frac1{2\sqrt n}$$
$$\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)=\log\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)\sim \frac1{n+1} $$
Hence you have:
$$(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)^a\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)\sim \frac{1}{n^{a/2+1}} $$
Can you take it from here?